# Different Project SDK and Language Level

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-12

I have recently downloaded IntelliJ IDEA (2018 version) and Java JDK 12. When I was configuring IntelliJ with JDK 12, the Project Language level is stuck at Java 9. Hence, I cannot use the new features in Java 12.

I have searched about this issue over the Internet, but this problem has not yet been identified, mostly because JDK 12 was released just last week (2019 March 19).

**Project Structure:**
[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 3):

To use new language feature of java12 you need [Intellij Idea 2019.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2019-1-java) which has Java 12 Switch Expressions (Preview) support. Then in project structure you could select language level:

[image]